# Why is reCaptcha Stealing Focus on Page Load

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Recaptcha has suddenly started stealing the focus when it's loaded on a page, which causes the page to scroll down to the form (very annoying). This appears to be a new bug?

See example: http://www.gullixson.com/Contact-Us

Apparently, the main Google Library that loads reCaptcha
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=UNIQUEAPIKEY&lang=en
calls for a http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_canary.js

In there, the init() function appears to fire a reload() function, which is causing the Recaptcha.focus_response_field() function to load.

There appears to be nothing we can do... until they fix it?

Does anyone know how to report this bug to Google? Or a way to work around this?

Comment: oh, that does look nasty! Maybe you can delay loading the ReCaptcha at all until the user scrolls it into view?

Comment: Ugh. I just started having this problem, too. I was about to post a question, but I found this one!

Comment: Google has fixed the bug, so this is no longer an issue (ATM), but if it happens in the future Mitch's answer is probably the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest workaround is just to redefine `Recaptcha.focus_response_field` after the recaptcha JS has loaded.

```
// Load recaptcha JS

// ...

Recaptcha.focus_response_field = function(){return false;};
```

This makes the focus operation essentially turn into a non-op.

Edit: Tested and working on Chrome, Firefox and IE9

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a little jQuery fix code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).focus(function(){
        /* If on load is detected a div to show reCaptcha code 
           ('div#captcha') simply force the focus to the top of the page. 
         */
       if( $('body').has('div#captcha') ){
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000, 'swing');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice hack. It seems like this will cause the page to scroll up after its scrolled down? I wonder what the timing will be, do you have an example in use? It's better than staying down, but still a wild ride for visitors :D

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround using jQuery:

```
<style>
#recaptcha_widget_div{
display: none;
}
</style>

...existing recaptcha code here...

<script>
$("body").on("focus", "input, textarea", function() {
    $("#recaptcha_widget_div").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad to see it's a widespread issue (which means it should be fixed soon hopefully). Interesting approach. Do you have an example in use? This seems like the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday.

Today, I checked again and it seems Google has fixed the problem.

You don't need to apply any hacks using jQuery anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the `Recaptcha.focus_response_field`:

```
Recaptcha.create("your_public_key", element, {
   theme: "red",
   callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field // <-- Comment this line
});
```